# Stellar.js - multiple backgrounds inside one element

Tags: parallax, stellar.js

I'm trying to use Stellar.js as multiple backgrounds inside of single element such as content. Anything that I've tried not working at all..

Default output look like this:

```css
  .photo {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: 50% 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 450px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .photo span {
   bottom: 0;
   color: white;
   display: block;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -640px;
   font-size: 38px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black, 0 0 10px black;
   width: 1280px;
  }
  .summer {
   background-image: url(images/1.png);
  }
  .autumn {
   background-image: url(images/2.png);
  }
  .winter {
   background-image: url(images/3.png);
  }
  .spring {
   background-image: url(images/4.png);
  }
```

```html
         <div class="photo summer" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Summer</span></div>
  <div class="photo autumn" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Autumn</span></div>
  <div class="photo winter" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Winter</span></div>
  <div class="photo spring" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Spring</span></div>
  <div class="photo summer" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Summer</span></div>
  <div class="photo autumn" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Autumn</span></div>
  <div class="photo winter" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Winter</span></div>
  <div class="photo spring" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><span>Spring</span></div>
```

But I want it to be something like that

```css
  .photo {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: 50% 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 450px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .photo span {
   bottom: 0;
   color: white;
   display: block;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -640px;
   font-size: 38px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black, 0 0 10px black;
   width: 1280px;
            background-image: url(images/1.png), url(images/2.png), url(images/3.png), url(images/4.png);
  }
```

```html
<div class="photo" data-stellar-background-ratio="1.0"><div>content</div></div>
```

I'm quite new to this and need some help. Maybe it just couldn't work as I want?